# traceable vs trackable: What is the difference (if any)?

Tags: adjectives

The title of this question is clear:

> "What is the difference (*if any*) between ***traceable*** vs ***trackable***?"

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: What did the dictionary have to say about the two words? What is your own comparative analysis after reading the various definitions for each?

Comment: trackable = (en adjective) Able to be tracked, or worthy of being tracked.
traceable = (en adjective) Capable of being traced; possible to track down.

Comment: Please read the help for our [tag:differences] tag to help improve your question.

Comment: I'm sorry for distressing you, I only want to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two terms which are often interchangeable appears to be their usage in the package delivery   industry:

> It would appear that the two words might be interchangeable. However, in the package delivery industry, “[track and trace](https://oilpatchwriting.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/trackable-vs-traceable/)” are used as two separate ideas.
>
> Tracking means determining the current location, and tracing means
> determining past locations of an item being delivered, generally using
> barcodes or RFID technology.
>
> Thus, tracing means following the footsteps or a continuous line of something with the goal of finding
> the route (the journey), whereas tracking means finding a spot here
> and there where intermittent tracks have been left with the goal of
> finding the item or animal (the destination).

(oilpatchwriting.wordpress.com)

Comment: Thank you mister user121863, your answer made me understand thoroughly the difference in their meanings! (y)

Answer (score 2):

Both are very similar terms that describe an the ability to determine where an object is at a certain point in time. Typically, tracking deals with the ability to find where something is at the current moment - if you are tracking an animal, or tracking a package you're shipping, you want to know where they are right now. Tracing, on the other hand, connotes a memory component, implying the ability to know the history of an item's location or origin.

A GPS tracker might show you where it is currently, but it wouldn't show you where it has been without additional software to keep a record. Conversely, contact tracing approaches for controlling the spread of coronavirus rely on retrospective analysis of contacts that have occurred in the past, rather than following a person's current movements.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_and_trace